# My jQuery is running a bit slow. How do I speed it up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there anything I can do to speed it up a bit? Or are there any rookie mistakes you notice?

I notice that I repeat a lot of variables. That's so I don't have to write out each line, but I'm not sure if there's a better solution?

The problem usually occurs when switching back to the tab after not being on it. It takes clicking the outer ring a few seconds to respond, but then it's fine. Almost like there's left over code running it needs to override? I'm not sure, but I'd love if an experienced user was able to brush their eyes over my code to see what could be improved.

Here's a working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eA6x6/1/, and below is the entirety of my javascript code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var timeoutHandle;

// hide stuff
    var hideServices = function() {
            jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "0"});
    };

    var hideAll = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".travel-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".events-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".adventurous-training-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".personal-injury-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".sports-and-tours-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".winter-sports-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});

            jQuery(".now-available").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".now-available-background").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".launched-shortly").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".launched-shortly-background").css({"opacity": "0"});
    };

    var showServicesDelay = function() {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "1"});
                hideAll();
        }, 5000);       
    };

// show messages
    var showLaunchedShortly = function() {
            jQuery(".launched-shortly").css({"opacity": "1"});
            jQuery(".launched-shortly-background").css({"opacity": "1"});
    };

    var showNowAvailable = function() {
            jQuery(".now-available").css({"opacity": "1"});
            jQuery(".now-available-background").css({"opacity": "1"});
    };

// show services
    var showMilitaryKit = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showProperty = function() {
            jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);    
    };

    var showHomeContents = function() {
            jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showTravel = function() {
            jQuery(".travel-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showEvents = function() {
            jQuery(".events-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showAdventurousTraining = function() {
            jQuery(".adventurous-training-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showPersonalInjury = function() {
            jQuery(".personal-injury-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showChallengePursuits = function() {
            jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showSportsAndTours = function() {
            jQuery(".sports-and-tours-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showWinterSports = function() {
            jQuery(".winter-sports-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };





// military kit
    jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(function() {        
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showMilitaryKit();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    });

// property
    jQuery(".property-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showProperty();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    }); 

// home contents
    jQuery(".home-contents-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showHomeContents();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    }); 

// travel
    jQuery(".travel-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showTravel();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    }); 

// events
    jQuery(".events-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showEvents();
        showServicesDelay();
        showLaunchedShortly();
    }); 

// adventurous training
    jQuery(".adventurous-training-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showAdventurousTraining();
        showServicesDelay();
        showLaunchedShortly();
    }); 

// personal injury
    jQuery(".personal-injury-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showPersonalInjury();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    }); 

// challenge pursuits
    jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showChallengePursuits();
        showServicesDelay();
        showNowAvailable();
    }); 

// sports and tours
    jQuery(".sports-and-tours-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showSportsAndTours();
        showServicesDelay();
        showLaunchedShortly();
    }); 

// winter sports
    jQuery(".winter-sports-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showWinterSports();
        showServicesDelay();
        showLaunchedShortly();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Things would be a lot simpler if you'd add supplementary classes to elements that get shown/hidden in similar circumstances.  That way you'd only need one selector.

Comment: Is this a tabbed interface? you if it is, you could probably cut your code down to ~ 15 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to speed up jQuery is to cache DOM elements to cut down on selecting the same element more than once, which involves a search of the DOM for that element each time - this can be slow and resource-heavy depending on how big or complex your DOM is.

An example based on your code:

```
var insigniaInner = jQuery('.insignia-inner'); //cache the div to a variable

...

//use the variable in your code instead of jQuery('.insignia-inner');
insigniaInner.css({"opacity":0});
```

you should see a significant speed increase if you use alot of selectors.

Edit: another way to speed up your code in particular would be to give all the elements you want to hide a common class, so you only need to do something like:

```
jQuery('.hide').hide();
```

This will also cut down on selector calls. Another way would be to target the parent element and fade or hide that instead of the individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could save a bit of download time by replacing jQuery with ($), as long as it doesn't conflict with any other libraries.

But also, you could assign all at once by replacing:

```
 var hideAll = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".travel-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".events-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".adventurous-training-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".personal-injury-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".sports-and-tours-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".winter-sports-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});

            jQuery(".now-available").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".now-available-background").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".launched-shortly").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".launched-shortly-background").css({"opacity": "0"});
    };
```

with something like:

```
 var hideAll = function() {
           $('[class $="-inner"]').css({"opacity": "0"});
           $(':not[class $="-inner"]').css({"opacity": "0"});
           //or, replace the line above with
           $('[class ^="now-available"]').css({"opacity": "0"});
           $('[class ^="launched-shortly"]').css({"opacity": "0"});
    };
```

That is just for example, but the logic may not be exactly what you are looking for (basically, everything that has a class in this example with have an opacity of 0).

Comment: `[class $= "-inner"]`

Comment: I'm running this on Wordpress, so I have to call a noncflict mode. The easiest way to do that is to replace $ with jQuery.

Comment: @A.Wolff, sorry, corrected.  `^` is begins with, where `$` is ends with.

Answer (score 0):

My guess the graphical stutter is caused when you "hide all" then "show one" at the same time (animations are asynchronous generally).  I don't think the code is running slowly, it's a graphics conflict.  Add a parameter "exceptThisOne" to the hideAll method and the hideServices method and make them case statements perhaps.  Up to you how you handle the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you can do but a good start would be to make sure you are using a custom .min version of jquery in production. Another would be combining some of these, for example:

```
jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
```

becomes

```
jQuery(".insignia-inner, .services-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
```

Jquery docs: Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/